# How can I customize hover for plotly.graph_object.Scattergeo?

Tags: python, plotly

I have problem to customize the hoverbox when ploting using ScatterGeo of Plotly.graphic_object. Specifically, I have dataframe like this

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'country': <list of country>,
                     'importValue': <list of data>,
                     'lat': <list of latitude for each country>,
                     'lon': <list of longitude for each country>,
```

Then, I plot using plotly as below:

```
 testFig = go.Figure()

 testFig.add_trace(go.Scattergeo(
           lon = data['lon'],
           lat = data['lat'],
           text = data['country'],
           marker = dict(
                size = data['value']/1000000,
                sizemode = 'area'
            ),
           hovertemplate = '<b>%{text}</b>'
        ))

 testFig.update_layout(autosize=False,
                       width=700,
                       height=700)

 testFig.show()
```

The hoverbox now just contains the name of country (like the figure below), I don't know how to add the value of column "importValue" to this hover.

Besides, I also would like to know how to change the background of the map for better vizualization. Using these lines of code just render the map with white color.

Please help! Thanks!

[image: plot rendered by my code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample data is taken from the geopandas dataset and mapped using a data frame with values and import values added as appropriate. For the user, import value, we set it up as custom data and added it to the hover template. The custom data requires an array, so we get the array from the data frame. Also, please refer to the reference for the map color and other settings. Since this is a geo-based map, decorations are limited.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np

geo_df = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_cities'))
geo_df['value'] = np.random.randint(1000,100000,len(geo_df))
geo_df['importValue'] = np.random.randint(10000,1000000,len(geo_df))

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scattergeo(lat=geo_df.geometry.y,
                            lon=geo_df.geometry.x,
                            text=geo_df["name"],
                            customdata=geo_df['importValue'].values,
                            marker = dict(
                                size = geo_df['value']/1000,
                                sizemode = 'area'
                            ),
                            hovertemplate = '<b>%{text}</b><br><b>ImportValue: %{customdata:,}</b>',
                            ))

fig.update_geos(
    showland=True, landcolor="white",
    showocean=True, oceancolor="LightBlue",)
fig.update_layout(autosize=False, width=1200, height=350)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I have other questions (1) as you can see on my fig, it has the word "trace 0", how can I get rid of that? (2) How can I modify the color according the given value in "customdata". (3) How can I add more data into the hover?

Comment: To remove the legend, I think you can set showlegend=False. Also, if you want to color-code the customdata, I am guessing that you can do so by setting a color list of the same length as geo_df['importValue'].values. I have not actually tried this, though.